# importing .sql file to cassandra

Tags: mysql, cassandra

**

Hi i am importing .sql file to cassandra.

cqlsh -f 'emptest.sql' -k employee 
emptest.sql:8:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ';' emptest.sql:9:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ';' emptest.sql:17:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ';' emptest.sql:23:Invalid syntax at char 22 emptest.sql:23: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `emptest`; emptest.sql:23: ^ emptest.sql:24:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ';' emptest.sql:25:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ';' emptest.sql:26:Invalid syntax at char 14 emptest.sql:26: CREATE TABLE `emptest` ( emptest.sql:26: ^ emptest.sql:27:Invalid syntax at char 3 emptest.sql:27: `emp_id` int(10) NOT NULL, emptest.sql:27: ^ emptest.sql:28:Invalid syntax at char 3 emptest.sql:28: `emp_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL, emptest.sql:28: ^ emptest.sql:29:Invalid syntax at char 3 emptest.sql:29: `emp_name` varchar(90) NOT NULL, emptest.sql:29: ^ emptest.sql:30:Invalid syntax at char 3 emptest.sql:30: `emp_phone` text NOT NULL, emptest.sql:30: ^ emptest.sql:31:Invalid syntax at char 3 emptest.sql:31: `emp_sal` text NOT NULL emptest.sql:31: ^ emptest.sql:32:Bad Request: line 1:0 no viable alternative at input ')' Can anyone help me on this.

### **

Comment: It means there's a syntax error. Try one command at a time.

Comment: You're trying to import SQL into a NoSQL database? That's not going to work. :)

Comment: Inserting data might work but the structural query will not be going to work.